# SQL Server 2005 unique key with null value

Tags: sql-server-2005, unique-key

I have a table in SQL Server 2005 with a foreign key, and I want that foreign key to be a unique value or null. I've set it up as a unique key, but it won't allow me to have multiple nulls in the same table. Is it possible to do what I want?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a long time complaint about SQL Server's Unique constraints/indexes. The best solution is to create a view with schemabinding and then put a unique index on that column:

```
Create View dbo.MyUniqueColView
With SchemaBinding
As
Select MyColToBeUnique
From MyTable
Where MyColToBeUnique Is Not Null

GO

Create Unique Clustered Index IX_MyTable_MyColToBeUnique On MyUniqueColView ( MyColToBeUnique )
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot enforce this with a table level constraint in SQL Server 2005 but you can create a view with definition `SELECT Col FROM t WHERE Col IS NOT NULL` and then create a unique clustered index on that.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2008, you could create a *[filtered index](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/01/sql-server-2008-introduction-to-filtered-index-improve-performance-with-filtered-index/)* on the values that are not null - unfortunately, that is a new feature in the 2008 release, so in 2005, you're not able to do anything like that, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Always an annoyance of mine. I prefer the "other" interpretation of the standard.

See [Creating a unique constraint that ignores nulls in SQL Server](http://improvingsoftware.com/2010/03/26/creating-a-unique-constraint-that-ignores-nulls-in-sql-server/). It covers three different approaches.

1. Solution 1: Filtered indexes.

   This seems pretty common, judging from other replies. I have not tried this approach -- it does *require* SQL Server 2008 though.
2. Solution 2: Constraint on computed column

   I have used this, and it does work. However, relationships may need to be adjusted and/or secondary non-unique covering indexed added (one for unique constraint, one for index cover).
3. Solution 3: UDF Check Constraint (Not recommended)

   Ahh, the power of TSQL (read: something *else* to deal with). I have not gone down this route.

Happy coding.